# Height of Div is too much, not getting reduced?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menubar with a few links in it. Here is my relevant code:

**CSS:**

```
#menuBar {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}
div#menuItem ul li {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
div#menuItem ul a {
    font-size:14px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menuBar">
<div id="menuItem"> 
<ul>
<li> <a href="index.php"> HOME</a> </li>
<li> <a href="index.php"> ABOUT</a> </li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- Menuitem closes -->
</div>
```

So, the Problem here is that the minimum height of the menuBar remains fixed. I want it to show up a little smaller. I try setting the padding of `#menuBar {padding -5px 0px }`. But, nothing happens.

How do I do that. And if I completly removing the code for padding. The height of the div becomes so small that it is just enough to accomodate the text.

Comment: Padding does not allow negative value

Comment: try property clear:both;

Comment: Why don't you just change the `margin` instead? http://jsfiddle.net/VDzcH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a height to the div... either by using the `line-height` or `height` properties.

Comment: Well then, tell me what you want because I got it to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/QhDhG/

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the `div#menuItem ul li` left, then add `display:block` to your `a` element and  an explicit `line-height` value.

```
div#menuItem ul li {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}

div#menuItem ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
 }​
```